# ListBox elements are duplicated when calling the selection of an index

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, duplicates, selecteditem

**Problem:**

I have a listbox that i fill with a dataset in that dataset i have row nombre and row cod_seg.
I assign row nombre to the property display member and the cod_seg to the property display member. In the selectindexchange event of that listbox  i create another dataset that bring me data that depends of the selectvalue of the listbox that happens without problem, the problem is that when i select one item of the listbox it duplicate the tem select in the listbox.

Dont know why this is happening and i check my code 10 times...

**Code: Fill Listbox**

```
private void FillData(int cs)
{
    CS = cs;


    ds.Clear();

    string cmd = "select CompaniaSeguro.Nombre,CompaniaSeguro.Telefono,CompaniaSeguro.Email from CompaniaSeguro where CompaniaSeguro.Cod_Comp = " + cs.ToString();
    ds = mytool.Execute(cmd);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        txtNC.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Nombre"].ToString();

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Telefono"].ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
            txtTelefono.Text = "No Asignado";
        else
            txtTelefono.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Telefono"].ToString();


        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Email"].ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
            txtEmail.Text = "No Asignado";
        else
            txtEmail.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();



    }

    ds.Clear();


    cmd = "select  Seguro.Cod_Seg , Seguro.Nombre from Seguro where Seguro.Cod_Comp = " + cs.ToString();
    ds = mytool.Execute(cmd);
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Cod_Seg";
        finish = true;

    }

}
```

**Code: Listbox selected index changed**

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (finish == true)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            DataSet myds = new DataSet();
            codS = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
            string cmd = "select Seguro.Nombre,Seguro.Descuento from Seguro where Seguro.Cod_Seg = " + codS;
            myds = mytool.Execute(cmd);

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("trae");
            }


        }
    }

}
```

**Image**

[Image](http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/4499/862x.png)

Comment: how if you remove codes in listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged method, is duplicate item still appear? Your code in that method seems not related to duplicate item in ListBox

Comment: If i remove the code the duplicate item doesn´t appear

Comment: what is mytool? And does the message box appear when selected index changed?

Comment: my tool is a class that i have for bring me a dataset of the command that i send, that works properly, yes the message box appear every time that the selected index is changed

Comment: it's hard to tell from here what was going wrong in your code. I tried to reproduce your case using listbox in winform and on selected index changed event doing similar logic with your code in that event, except i'm using DataTable instead of DataSet. But no duplicate item appear.

Comment: you need to make small apps that still showing similar problem in order to enable SO members to help futher. Or you can trace the problem source yourself, there are only few lines in listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged method so it wont be a lot of work. Try to begin with commenting all lines inside `if (listBox1.SelectedValue != null)` block. Then begin to uncomment line(s) by line(s) to see which line is exactly causing the duplicate.

Comment: I notice that if i fill a dataset and i use that dataset like a datasource for a datagrid , if i fill another dataset that brings  data with my class, the dataset will join or something like that in the datagridview...like i use two datasets that bring me different data in the listbox maybe my data tool class (mytool object) is the problem. There is a difference of having a dinamic class instead of a static one?  I will keep your advice and I'll make a small app that emulates the behavior of the problem, I'll see if the same thing happens if I do it with my class data tools.